# stick breaking model of Dirichlet process

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, dirichlet-distribution, nonparametric-bayes, dirichlet-process

I have a question regarding sticking-breaking model of Dirichlet process, which is defined as follows:

[image]

There are further statements that

[image]

I am not clear that how to derive equation 1 from that posterior distribution and why does the equation 1 is equal to equation 2. Here $\mathcal{B}$ is Beta distribution.

Comment: Beta distribution is just a two dimensional Dirichlet.

Comment: Isn't the [Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) a one-dimensional distribution of continuous proportions?

Comment: Yes. Assume the proportion is p. p follows a Beta, then [p,1-p] follows a 2d Dirichlet.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that the Dirichlet is a 2D Beta?

Comment: @gung I don't know if you sorted that yet, but no, the Dirichlet Distribution is not a 2d beta.
In general, its support is the simplex $(p_1,p_2,...,p_k)$ with the sum of $p_j$ equals to 1 and $p_j>0$. i.e. its a $k$-dimensional distribution lives on a $k-1$-dimensional surface. E.g.: the 2d Dirichlet only has parameters $p$ and $1-p$. So the 2d Dirichlet distribution is just directly the beta distribution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend you to read Introduction to the [Dirichlet Distribution and Related Processes](http://mayagupta.org/publications/FrigyikKapilaGuptaIntroToDirichlet.pdf) by Bela A. Frigyik, Amol Kapila, and Maya R. Gupta. It is written in a very accessible manner, and I could imagine, it would be a great introduction to those topics (measure theory, etc)

Hope it helps

Comment: Wow, this is a *great* tutorial.